# Is it possible to turn a led on and off after every apache request

Tags: python, apache, raspberry-pi, mod-wsgi, raspberry-pi4

I try now for 2 weeks to turn a led on after someone opens my website. the order should be like that:

1. Request received
2. Led turns on and 0.5 seconds later off again
3. Response is send back

I have a Raspberry Pi to turn on my led.

my python code till now:

```
import time
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

pin = 4

GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(pin, GPIO.OUT)

GPIO.output(pin, GPIO.HIGH)
time.sleep(0.1)
GPIO.output(pin, GPIO.LOW)
```

It worked sometimes but then now website was shown.
I tryed it with WSGI but it is a bit complicated.
Maybe someone had the same idea and it works for him and he could help me.

Comment: You would need to use "hooks" to integrate your bit of Python code with apache. The `mod_wsgi` module allows such hooks to be made, see e.g. the tutorial https://www.toptal.com/python/pythons-wsgi-server-application-interface

Comment: @EvertW do you know how to make such a hook with wsgi because your tutorial makes a response but i dont want that python makes a response but my webserver apache should respond with the requested file

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any Apache at all or anything complicated for that, you can just add the bits to turn LED on and off into the simple web-server class Python provides.

Just adapt the IP address and port at the top of this code and run it in Terminal and connect to the address it is serving:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

#import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import os
from time import sleep
from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer

host_name = '192.168.0.8'
host_port = 63000
pin = 4

class MyServer(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):

    def do_HEAD(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header('Content-type', 'text/html')
        self.end_headers()

    def do_GET(self):
        html = '''
           <html>
           <body style="width:960px; margin: 20px auto;">
           <h1>Welcome to my Raspberry Pi</h1>
           </body>
           </html>
        '''

        # You may want to move these 3 setup lines to the very start of the program
        GPIO.setwarnings(False)
        GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
        GPIO.setup(pin, GPIO.OUT)

        GPIO.output(pin, GPIO.HIGH)
        sleep(0.1)
        GPIO.output(pin, GPIO.LOW)

        self.do_HEAD()
        self.wfile.write(html.encode("utf-8"))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    http_server = HTTPServer((host_name, host_port), MyServer)
    print("Server Starts - %s:%s" % (host_name, host_port))

    try:
        http_server.serve_forever()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        http_server.server_close()
```

Comment: That is a great idea but i have already a fully configured apache server and just want to run a bit of python before apache sends a response back